# Circles Around Circles With Text In

Tags: css

How would I make the "yes!!!" text in the following code appear centred in the circle?

I've tried adding padding, but it just moves the text to the right, i.e., the padding is not applied evenly in all directions.

Here's my code (http://jsfiddle.net/yxVkk/646/)

The HTML:-

```
<div id="big-circle" class="circle big">
<div class="circle one"><span style="top: -50px;">YES!!!</span></div>
<div class="circle two"></div>
<div class="circle three"></div>
<div class="circle four"></div>
<div class="circle five"></div>
<div class="circle six"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:-

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.circle.big {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 100px;
    }

    .one {
    left: -100px;
    top: -100px;
    }

    .two {
    top: -60px;
    left: 50px;
    }

    .three {
    right: -25px;
    top: -25px;
}


    .four {
        left: -25px;
        bottom: -25px;
        }

        .five {
        bottom: -60px;
    left: 50px;
    }

    .six {
    right: -25px;
    bottom: -25px;
    }
```

Note: I would prefer to accomplish this without JS, as in the above example.

Comment: your fiddle failes to open

Comment: @rub There were just a couple stray characters in the link; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `style="top: -50px;"` and add

```
.one>span{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align:center
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxVkk/648/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your span a position first of all, and then push it around with left and top:

```
.one span {
     position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxVkk/647/